Squid proxy running on Red Hat Linux returning 400 server error when trying to connect LimaCharlie Sensor
I have a simple setup consisting of a Red Hat Linux virtual machine running Squid Proxy and a second Red Hat Linux virtual machine that will connect trough the proxy.

Client
The client should run a LimaCharlie Sensor:
sudo ./lc_sensor -d AAAABgAAAQsFAAAAI2I3Ra/tCbGrUhKMDRhoUECAwEAAQ==

But it gives the following error:
WARNING ====== bin/linux/4.0/x86_64/release/lib/rpHostCommonPlatformLib/beacon.c: 1030 thread_conn() 1718011483 - connecting to b76093c3662d5b4f.lc.limacharlie.io:443
WARNING ====== bin/linux/4.0/x86_64/release/lib/networkLib/networkLib.c: 2804 NetLib_ConnectProxy() 1718011483 - proxy CONNECT failure: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/5.5
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2024 09:24:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;ch

I know that curl works over the proxy:
[azureuser@vm-rh-client1 ~]$ curl -O -L "https://www.redhat.com/index.html " -x "10.0.0.4:3128"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  200k    0  200k    0     0   469k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  317k

Proxyserver:
In the logs of Squid Proxy I find this error:
1717589262.730      0 10.0.0.5 NONE_NONE/400 4394 CONNECT b76093c3662d5b4f.lc.limacharlie.io:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html

This is my config for Squid:
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/24
#acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10         # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
#acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16        # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16                # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src fc00::/7              # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10             # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128


http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#

What can I do to debug this issue?
